# Rails ActiveRecord join three tables and retrieve nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three model classes: Games, Teams, and Players:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  has_many :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end

class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.string :play_date
      t.string :date

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreateTeams < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :teams do |t|
      t.integer :team_number
      t.references :game, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :teams, :games
  end
end

class CreatePlayers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :players do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :team, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :players, :teams
  end
end
```

I am trying to write an Active Record query to return an object that contains nested objects for 1 game, M number of teams, N number of players.  So, for example, I am expecting my returned data to look something like this:

```
{ "id" => "1", "play_date"=>"2016-01-28", 
  "teams" =>
  [{"id" => "1", "game_id" => "1", "team_number" => "1", 
    "players" =>
    [{"id" => "1", "team_id" => "1", "name" => "Jim"},
     {"id" => "2", "team_id" => "1", "name" => "Bob"},
     {"id" => "3", "team_id" => "1", "name" => "Sally"}
    ]
   },
   {"id" => "2", "game_id" => "1", "team_number" => "2", 
    "players" =>
    [{"id" => "4", "team_id" => "2", "name" => "Ed"},
     {"id" => "5", "team_id" => "2", "name" => "Molly"},
     {"id" => "6", "team_id" => "2", "name" => "Tim"}
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

The closest I've been able to get this to working is the following:

```
@data = Player.select("players.*, teams.*").joins(team: :game).where(games: {id: params[:id]})
```

which returns something like:

```
[
#<Player id: 1, name: "Jim", team_id: 1, created_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52", updated_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52">, 
#<Player id: 2, name: "Bob", team_id: 1, created_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52", updated_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52">, 
#<Player id: 3, name: "Sally", team_id: 1, created_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52", updated_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52">, 
#<Player id: 4, name: "Ed", team_id: 2, created_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52", updated_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52">, 
#<Player id: 5, name: "Molly", team_id: 2, created_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52", updated_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52">, 
#<Player id: 6, name: "Tim", team_id: 2, created_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52", updated_at: "2016-01-02 19:27:52">
]
```

I've tried multiple variations of the above code to try to get a set of nested objects like in my expected output example, but I always get results that return only a single level of objects.

Can anyone help return results that contain nested objects?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I needed to take a break, I was able to figure this out now.

I think my issue was with relying on the .inspect command to check and see if my multiple levels of objects were being loaded.  Turns out if I just simplified my query to:

```
@data = Game.joins(teams: :players).find(params[:id])
```

and then actually tried looping through the data in my view:

```
<% @data.teams.each do |team| %>
  <%= team.players[0].name %>
<% end %>
```

This allowed me to access all of the data I needed.  I'm guessing due to lazy loading (but maybe not) inspect doesn't show all of the data.